# Rviz2 and Gazebo dependencies conflict

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

what's the correct way for installing Gazebo in a system with ROS2 Crystal?

The following instructions are not working at the moment

```
$ docker run -it osrf/ros:crystal-desktop bash

$ apt-get update
$ curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgazebo9-dev : Depends: libavdevice-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libignition-fuel-tools1-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libignition-common-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgazebo9 (= 9.8.0-1~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gazebo9-plugin-base (= 9.8.0-1~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note that I get a very similar error also if I run

```
$ apt-get install -y ros-crystal-gazebo-ros-pkgs
```

As a solution, I have explicitly installed some dependencies before calling the gazebo install command

```
$ apt-get install -y \
   libwayland-egl1 \
   libsdl2-2.0-0 \
   libavdevice57
$ apt-get install -y \
   libgazebo9-dev \
   gazebo9
$ apt-get install -y  ros-crystal-gazebo-ros-pkgs
```

This works, but as a result I can't run `rviz2` anymore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319904/rviz2-and-gazebo-dependencies-conflict/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2019-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the following commands I am able to install and run both:

```
docker pull osrf/ros:crystal-desktop
docker run -it   -e DISPLAY   -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1   -e XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH   -v "$XAUTH:$XAUTH"   -v "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix"   -v "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"  osrf/ros:crystal-desktop
apt -qq update
apt -qq upgrade -y
apt install -y ros-crystal-gazebo-ros-pkgs
rviz2
gazebo
```

I'm not familiar with the content of the `get.gazebosim.org` script but it may be trying to pull a newer version of gazebo (from `http://packages.osrfoundation.org`) than the ubuntu version (9.0.0).

HTH,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2019-03-29**:
This works and it's better than my command.
Actually I think that my problem was also due to the use of a not up-to-date base image

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-03-29**:
BTW @marguedas  you might find rocker useful if you're running gui's inside docker  https://github.com/osrf/rocker it's available from the ROS repos as python3-rocker or via PIP.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-30**:
If you don't need all of the isolation of Docker (but are using it more as part of a deployment system), you could also take a look at [Singularity](https://www.sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/). Wrappers like `rocker` aren't really needed with it.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2019-03-30**:
Wow that's really cool I didnt know about rocker!
Thanks guys for sharing!